# How to solve OLEDB provider to work for different versions of Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

We have Windows Server 2012 R2 With SQL Server 2012 on our machine, Microsoft Access database Engine 2010 is also installed.

We have problem with Excel files .xls and .xlsx. We have an application where we import Exel files.

When we have applicationpool set to false we get following error:
    *(Enable 32-bit applications = False)*
        **'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**
Only .xlsx files works.

When we have applicationpool set to true we get following error:
    *(Enable 32-bit applications = True)*
      **'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**
Only .xls files works.

How to solve this so we can use both file types?

Comment: Why not test the incoming files and then change the property accordingly?

Comment: Do you mean that we Will do this test in application layer?

Comment: Yes.  Test for file type and then change the setup accordingly.